# UIProgressView setCornerRadius working "Sometimes"

Tags: ios, uiprogressview, cornerradius

I created `UIProgressView` in a custom cell and I added this,

```
[cell.progressView.layer setCornerRadius:4];
```

This didn't work with my `UIProgressView` **sometimes** !!

I used to delete this line accidentally, but even it worked sometimes WOW!

How could I overcome this situation?

Thank you very much.

P.S.>> I created a custom cell (subclassed of UICollectionViewCell) named **ConanCell**, XIB file.

In.h

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIProgressView *progressView;
```

In ViewController.m

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ConanCell *cell = (ConanCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell.progressView setProgress:0.7];
    [cell.progressView.layer setCornerRadius:4];
}
```

Comment: post your code so we can help you - how you create the cell, how you create progressView, etc

Comment: @almas added! hope it helps you see something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could solved this issue by setting the corner radius like

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     ConanCell *cell = (ConanCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell.progressView setProgress:0.7];
    [cell.progressView.layer setCornerRadius:4];
     cell.progressView.layer.masksToBounds = TRUE;
     cell.progressView.clipsToBounds = TRUE;
 }
```